# htaccess only allow active php session

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

I know there's a way but can't figure this out. How can I get htaccess run a php script to see if $_SESSION['user'] is active and allow the page go through or ELSE return a 404 if session not active?

I seen RewriteMAP script be keeps on crashing.

I am running debian with root access

Comment: You're usually better off handling this at the PHP level; you don't want a `.htaccess` misconfiguration opening up your whole site to the public. You could *potentially* use `auto_prepend_file` though.

Comment: _"I seen RewriteMAP script be keeps on crashing."_ - a RewriteMap script needs to be _continuously_ running, and respond quickly, when it gets some new input passed via stdin. But with PHP locking the session file when a script instance is still actively using it, you'd probably produce a lot of "hangups" here, if you tried to make a RewriteMap script actually read the session file to validate the session was still valid.